# Loading data from R into PostgrSQL database

Tags: r, postgresql

I am working with large dataset and trying to load the data from R into PostgrSQL database. Using the below statement, the loading is essentially taking hours to load. Here is the statement I am using.

```
dbWriteTable(con, "Table_Name", df, overwrite = FALSE, append=TRUE)
```

Is there any other, potentially quicker way to load the data. Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tested with sample records (<1k) and it successfully read, load and saved the data into a database. So not sure the distinction on the comment you made on "not to read from it"

Comment: Sorry Neel, I misread and deleted my comment. Otherwise, I'm not sure what else can be done. How many cases and variables are you trying to write in? Are you referring to the DBI function?

Comment: Hey no worries. Yeah its the DBI function and I am writing a dataframe fom R into a database which has more than 5mm records.